# What is "In a feature in 1964"?

Tags: word-meaning, phrase-meaning

> A small article appeared outlining the strange disappearances of ships and planes. The area was given the name The Devil’s Sea. **In a feature in 1964**, Vincent Gaddis christened the area the Bermuda Triangle.

(from https://zno.osvita.ua/english/all/480/)

What does the phrase in bold mean?

Answer (score 2):

A *feature* is a term for television or radio programme or film (movie), or a longer, more developed piece in a newspaper or magazine. The general connotation is that it is not a run-of-the-mill piece of *whatever*, but something that took considerable work. What it refers to specifically might be discerned from context, though it might depend on the specific dialect and when it was spoken/written.

Thus, this indicates that there was a TV or radio programme, a film or a magazine/newspaper piece published in 1964, in which Vincent Gaddis gave the name "Bermuda Triangle" to the area in question.